# Color-highlight a single key in a python wordcloud.WordCloud data-viz when also using a color_func

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, word-cloud

I'm looking for a way to change a single element of a color mapping in python (to highlight one specific key).

To debug, I tried to run a hard-coded update for the hsl at list position 0 to [50,50,50] and I can see it updates the mapping... but has no impact on the color - any ideas what is happening?

```
wordcloud7 = WordCloud(width = 800, height = 800, background_color=background_translation, mask=mask,
                        prefer_horizontal=1, font_path=font_file, min_font_size = 2, 
                        max_words = 500).generate_from_frequencies(keys_values_dict)

wordcloud7.recolor(color_func = grey_color_func)
for i in range(len(wordcloud7.color_func.colormap.colors[0])):
  wordcloud7.color_func.colormap.colors[0][i] = 50
print(wordcloud7.color_func.colormap.colors)

plt.figure(figsize = (14, 14), facecolor = None)
plt.imshow(wordcloud7)
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout(pad = 0)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not completely clear what you are trying to achieve.
The [`color_func`](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html#wordcloud.WordCloud) gets six input parameters (`word, font_size, position, orientation, font_path, random_state`) and should return a color in ["PIL color" format](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageColor.html#color-names). Examples for colors are names such as 'dodgerblue', 'crimson', ... or numbers in the format (R, G, B) with integer values between 0 en 255. Using equal R, G and B values creates a shade of grey.

Here is an example coloring one word in 'turquoise', one in 'limegreen' and the rest using the 'inferno' colormap depending on their font size.

```py
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def test_color_func(word, font_size, position, orientation, font_path, random_state):
    print(word, font_size)
    if word == 'Germany':
        return 'turquoise'
    elif word == 'France':
        return 'limegreen'
    else:
        r, g, b, alpha = plt.get_cmap('inferno')(font_size / 120)
        return (int(r * 255), int(g * 255), int(b * 255))

keys_values_dict = {'France': 65269, 'Germany': 83911, 'United Kingdom': 67921, 'Italy': 60473, 'Spain': 46781,
                    'Ukraine': 43742, 'Poland': 37854, 'Romania': 19224, 'Netherlands': 17135, 'Belgium': 11597}
wordcloud7 = WordCloud(width=800, height=800, background_color='white',
                       prefer_horizontal=1).generate_from_frequencies(keys_values_dict)
wordcloud7.recolor(color_func=test_color_func)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5), facecolor=None)
plt.imshow(wordcloud7)
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: example word cloud]